# Passing data to activity from widget

Tags: android

I am trying to pass data from widget to activity and I always receive null.
Here is onUpdate from widget class:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);

        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
        configIntent.putExtra("URL", "Content");
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonOpen, configPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);


    String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
    Log.d("DTAG","URL: "+sessionId); //Is null

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(sessionId);
}
```

}

Comment: `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0)` is not going to work for your scenario. Use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` for the second `0`, and consider using unique ID values for each `PendingIntent` for each app widget in place of your first `0`.

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to replace extras in a `PendingIntent`, you need to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` for the final parameter to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. Otherwise, the extras in your new `Intent` will be ignored.

And, if you wish to have different extras for different `PendingIntent` objects (e.g., per widget ID), you need to pass a unique ID as the second parameter to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. If you use `0` all the time, you get exactly one `PendingIntent` with one set of extras.